# MySQL query to calculate rent owed based on a partial payment

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I could probably do the following via PHP code but I feel it could most likely been accomplished in MySQL, so just looking for someone to help me out on a query.

I have a contract table which defines a customer monthly payment, let's say for example it is £500 per month. I then have another table called rent, where every month rent is inputted. Each rent has a status called Paid, Unpaid and Partial.

My query so far is the following, do I have to do multiple sub-queries, or is their a simple way.

```
SELECT cc.property_id, cc.property_rent, r.order_total, r.order_status,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_status = 'Partial' THEN cc.property_rent - r.order_total ELSE 0 END) AS partial_rent_owed
FROM t_customers_contract cc JOIN
     t_customers_rent r
     ON cc.customer_id = r.customer_id                                                   WHERE cc.property_id = 62 AND r.transaction_type = 'rent' AND
      (r.date_created BETWEEN '2017-04-05' AND '2019-04-05')
GROUP BY cc.property_id
```

Basically, if the rent status is partial then subtract it from what is usually and then total sum of what is owed.

The desired result would be in the total SUM of what is owed and what has been contributed per property as a following output:

property_id, total_rent_made, total_rent_owed

The current contract table structure and data is as follows:

[image: Contract table]

The current rent table structure and data is as follows:

[image]

As you can see order_id 20 and 27 are Partial payments and the actual payment to be made based on the contract for these ID's should be 750 and 700.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, let me arrange this for you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I have just updated the main description, is that any better?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve it, it is the following query. If anyone can improve it, happy to take a suggestion based on performance or it being more cleaner.

```
SELECT cc.property_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_status = 'Partial' THEN (cc.property_rent - r.order_total) ELSE 0 END) AS partial_rent_owed
FROM t_customers_contract cc JOIN t_customers_rent r ON (cc.property_id = r.property_id)
WHERE cc.contract_id = r.contract_id
AND cc.customer_id = 7866
AND r.transaction_type = 'rent'
AND (r.date_created BETWEEN '2016-04-05' AND '2019-04-05')
GROUP BY cc.property_id
```

Comment: How do you record multiple partial payments applied to a single month of rent? Do late fees come into play?

Comment: The user will simply update the current rent amount and make a note. Any late fees will be implied as expenses.